# Roman desks and lacquer

Tags: ancient-history, rome

I've been watching the Netflix piece on Ancient Rome and noticed a beautifully lacquered desk which I felt might not be accurate for the time. Does anyone have information about their use of lacquer for their furniture?

Comment: Lacquer comes from [a tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toxicodendron_vernicifluum) cultivated in India/China/Japan, so ancient Romans could have had some imported lacquered furniture but it'd be pretty rare. Could you post a picture of the desk you're talking about? It could just be stylized wood with a nice coating of resin [varnish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varnish#Etymology) rather than actual lacquer.